# How to get users with 3 or more consecutive weeks in order?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user table like this,

```
name      week_no   year_no
fb        5         2021
twitter   1         2022
twitter   2         2022
twitter   3         2022
twitter   7         2022
youtube  21         2022
```

I want to find the names of users who login >= 3 consecutive weeks in the same year. The week numbers will be unique for each year. For example, in the above table we can see that user `twitter` is logged in `week_no: 1, 2, 3` in the same year `2022` thereby satisfying the condition that I am looking for.

The output I am looking for,

```
name        year_no
twitter     2022
```

You can create the sample table using,

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    name varchar(20),
    week_no int,
    year_no int
);
INSERT INTO test (name, week_no, year_no)
VALUES ('fb', 5, 2021), 
       ('twitter', 1, 2022),
       ('twitter', 2, 2022),
       ('twitter', 3, 2022), 
       ('twitter', 7, 2022),
       ('youtube', 21, 2022);
```

I am new to SQL language and I read that group by can achieve that, can someone help in what function/query we have to use to achieve the same.

```
select * from test group by year_no, name;
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Please include which version of MySql you are using

Comment: @stu I am trying out my code here in this website: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ using postgresql 9.6

Comment: So you're not actually using MySql at all? Why tag MySql and not Postgres?

Comment: @Stu In production we are using mysql 8, but I am trying out in sqlfiddle on a sample of data.

Comment: @Stu I'll remove postgresql tag from the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You need to be clear which platform you require a solution for or actually state both, since SQL dialects and functionality can vary greatly between platforms and different versions.

Comment: @Stu, I am sorry for the confusion. Won't happen again. MYSQL 8 is the version I will be using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution which will work on every MySQL version, without using windows function. Join the same table 3 times

```
SELECT t1.name,t1.year_no
FROM   test t1
INNER JOIN   test t2 ON t1.name=t2.name AND t1.year_no=t2.year_no
INNER JOIN   test t3 ON t1.name=t3.name AND t1.year_no=t3.year_no
WHERE  t2.week_no = t1.week_no + 1 
AND    t3.week_no = t1.week_no + 2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/XjeXKUFE

Comment: This is not taking year into consideration. Same week number 1 could be presented in year 2021 then this is failing.

Comment: If the table is `INSERT INTO test (name, week_no, year_no) VALUES ('fb', 5, 2021), ('twitter', 1, 2021), ('twitter', 1, 2022), ('twitter', 2, 2022), ('twitter', 3, 2022),  ('twitter', 7, 2022), ('youtube', 21, 2022);` then this is failing.

Comment: @user_12 updated, I missed that part...added the year on the join condition

Answer (score 2):

You may define a unique groups for consecutive weeks in the same year and aggregate them as the following:

```
SELECT name, year_no
FROM
(
  SELECT *, 
   week_no -
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by name, year_no ORDER BY week_no) grp
 FROM test
) T
GROUP BY name, year_no, grp
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
ORDER BY name, year_no
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JnTaTrGW).

Answer (score 1):

Window function version.
[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/G9k3nq9T)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        week_no,
        year_no,
        lag(week_no) OVER (PARTITION BY name,
            year_no ORDER BY year_no,
            week_no) AS lag,
        lead(week_no) OVER (PARTITION BY name,
            year_no ORDER BY year_no,
            week_no) AS lead
    FROM
        testuser
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    name,
    year_no
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    lead + lag = 2 * week_no;
```